# How to delete a repository using GitHub API?

Tags: git, curl, github

So I'm trying to delete a bunch of repos (where I'm the contributor) from a dummy organisation where I'm the owner. I'm following the GitHub documentation here - https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository

Since it's a GitHub Enterprise account, the URL endpoint is slightly different.

Here's my cURL command which is throwing errors for me:

`curl -i -H 'Authorization: token {token}' DELETE 'https://{hostname}/api/v3/repos/{myUsername}/{reponame}'`

Is there something very wrong I'm doing? I've tried different combinations after looking up a similar question on here but nothing seems to work.

Here's the cURL output:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: DELETE
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Thu, 14 Sep 2017 16:45:20 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 102
Status: 404 Not Found
X-OAuth-Scopes: repo, user
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: repo
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3; format=json
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-GitHub-Request-Id: ce484b8e-e6fb-41b3-aaca-65b047be1e3f
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.9/v3"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the documentation says:

```
DELETE /repos/:owner/:repo
```

It is instructing you to use the HTTP verb "DELETE", which is done in curl using "-X DELETE":

```
curl -i -X DELETE -H 'Authorization: token {token}' 'https://{hostname}/api/v3/repos/{myUsername}/{reponame}'
```

(I haven't tested this yet, so there may be other issues, but hopefully it will help as a start.)

Comment: It did not :( I still get a 404! What could be the issue? It can't be authentication/authorization, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your curl request is wrong. Below should work:

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: token {token}' -X 'DELETE' 'https://{hostname}/api/v3/repos/{myUsername}/{reponame}'
```

DELETE here is a HTTP method just like GET and POST. In curl, you need to specify the HTTP method in -X parameter.

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't help - I receive the same response as above :( What other issue could it be? Surely not authentication/authorization...?

Comment: It seems the API endpoint you are sending request to is invalid. Does repository {myUsername}/{reponame} exists? Please debug on these lines.

Comment: I'll investigate that! Thank you!